# Connecting hub to 1 USB port vs 2 USB ports?

Tags: usb, usb-power, usb-hub

The Pi 4B has 2x USB 3.0 ports. I have 2 choices to connect my hard drives:

1. Using a single 10-port hub which connects to 1 USB 3.0 port.
2. Using two 5-port hubs which connect to two USB 3.0 ports.

Which is better for my setup in term of bandwith? In other words, does the 2 USB 3.0 ports belong to an integrated hub and share the same root port, like the 4 USB 2.0 ports (2x USB2 + 2xUSB3 working in 2.0 mode) do?

By the way, the 10-port hub has a 12V 4A power adapter, while the 5-port hub has 5V 2A adapter (with a variation with 12V 2A available). Which one should I get? I have a total of 10 3.5" HDDs, which connected to Seagate HDD docks. That dock takes a 12V 1.5A input, but I am not sure if it provides 5V power to the HDD or relies on 5V from the USB connection.

[image]

Comment: 3.5inch "spinning rust" HDD's need 12V - unless something has changed in the last few years

Comment: @Bravo I already know that, as stated in the question. What I do not know is whether they take 5V from the dock (adapter) or from USB connection.

Comment: If you really want to know buy an USB adapter that measures the USB voltage and current. Typically one would expect that a self-powered HDD dock uses it's power adapter for both required voltages.